# Pointer release event not triggered for outside dropped UI element in UWP

Tags: uwp, drag-and-drop, event-handling

I am working on one task in UWP Drag and Drop functionality. I can able to drag and drop an UI element in parent canvas. But if I try to drop the UI element outside of the canvas, not getting any event for that.

Tried with **PointerReleased** event, but not worked.

Anyone know to capture the pointer release event (both touch and mouse click drag) in drag and drop?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Pointer release event not triggered for outside dropped UI element in UWP

It's by-design, PointerReleased has been hold up by `Drop` event, and you could use it to replace `PointerReleased`.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TargetTextBox"
         AllowDrop="True"         
         Drop="TargetTextBox_Drop"
         DragEnter="TargetTextBox_DragEnter"
         DragLeave="TargetTextBox_DragLeave"
         AcceptsReturn="True"
         MinHeight="120"
         />

private async void TargetTextBox_Drop(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.DragEventArgs e)
{

}
```

For more detail, please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/drag-and-drop#process-the-drop-event).